# JavaScript floating point precision issue

Tags: javascript, precision, trigonometry

I am encountering a floating point precision issue, does anybody know why this happens? Why is it that the cosine function is affected, but not he sine function.

```
Math.sin(90 * Math.PI / 180);
// returned: 1, expected: 1

1 - Math.sin(90 * Math.PI / 180);
// returned: 0, expected: 0


Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / 180);
// returned: 6.123233995736766e-17, expected: 0

1 - Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / 180);
// returned: 0.9999999999999999, expected: 1
```

Comment: This is just a common issue with all languages, but mainly because using floating point math leads to rounding errors. Your best best is just rounding it unfortunately...

Comment: But why is it just cosine that's affected, and not the sine function? (updated my question to reflect this comment).

Comment: @RobertoAureli, could you please elaborate? I'm not quite sure what you mean there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol, no it's not. My question is it, with the equation demonstrated in my example, that only the cosine function returned an incorrect value? Sine returned exactly 1 or 0, whereas cosine did not.

Comment: Just like `0.1+0.1 == 0.2` but `0.2+0.1 != 0.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical answer to this one is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

With a little more trying you will find examples for "unexpected" results with the sine function.

E.g. `Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / 180);`

Comment: I know why floating point accuracy errors occur, my question is, why is it just the cosine that returns an incorrect value for the equation demonstrated?