# javascript toString() does weird things with long numbers... why? And is there a work around?

Tags: javascript

If you create the following function, and execute, you will get a return of: 11111111111111112.  If you do much more, you will get exponential numbers.  I just want to take long strings of numbers and place them into an array (the follow-up would be a split on the function).  Is there anyway around this weirdness?

```js
function sum2one(num) {
  var numtostring = num.toString();
  console.log(numtostring);
}

sum2one(11111111111111111);
```

Comment: blame the IEEE, and just store strings...

Comment: I think this is just a matter of the nature of the one Number type in javascript? For really big numbers I think scientific notation is probably a better way to go about it? @dandavis, are you sure storing strings as opposed to an actual number is a safe way to go (what happens if you need to perform arithmetic operations with those stored strings)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299407/javascript-floating-point-precision-issue

Comment: or check a big number implementation (it might be slow, but you will be able to perform calculation on them and get consistent string representation)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), though at the other end of the spectrum.

Comment: It's not the `toString` function that does anything weird. It's the parser that converts your literal to a representable number. Simply try `console.log(11111111111111111)` or `console.log(11111111111111111 + 0)`.

Comment: Thank you, all.  Makes sense.

Comment: _"I just want to take long strings of numbers and place them into an array"_ How are the numbers generated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867648/why-does-this-number-get-increased-by-one

Comment: See also [Converting large numbers from binary to decimal and back in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39334494/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript numbers are always 64-bit floating point numbers. That is why. That basically leads to the fact that for every number there is no exact integer representation.

So, in fact, toString() doesn't do the weird things. It is the actual format how the numbers are stored/represented/implemented in the javascript language.

What!? Is floating point math broken?! Not really, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Very much appreciated

Comment: Would have loved to.  It won't let me upvote until I got a high enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript [uses 64-bit floating point numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).
I don't think it's possible to store precise numbers in javascript.

There are alternatives, bigint libraries can help. But you should just store as a string.

- http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html
- http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/
- https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to take long strings of numbers and place them into an
>   array

You can use `Array.prototype.fill()`.

```js
function sum2one(num, len, from, to, arr) {
  return  (arr 
          ? len > arr.length 
            ? (arr = [...arr, ...Array(len - arr.length)]) 
            : arr 
          : Array(len))
          .fill(num, from || 0, to || len)
}

let arr = sum2one(1, 17);

console.log(arr);

// set index 13

arr[13] = 2;

console.log(arr);

// fill indexes 14 through 21

arr = sum2one(3, 21, 14, 21, arr);

console.log(arr);
```